# Setting variable value based on spring profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-annotations, spring-config

How to assign value to variable based on region?

Lets says

`system properties`, 
`dev-url="dev-abc.com"`,
`prod-url="prod-abc.com"` and
`qa-url="qa-abc.com"`

```
@Value( #{systemProperties. ??? )
String url;
```

Comment: Do you mean you have all these 3 kind of url variable and you want to set String url based on your spring profile?

Comment: You must have different `.properties` obviously . you can get according to the environment

Answer (score 5):

if you have all properties inside on property file you can use :

```
 @Value("${spring.profiles.active}-url") String url;
```

Comment: Yes I'm using only one property file and I'm not interested in using 3 property files

I tried your below suggestion 

@Value( #{systemProperties[${spring.profiles.active}'-url'] ) String url;

but it is not working.Is any changes required in spel ?

Comment: use  @Value("${spring.profiles.active}-url") String url;

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to avoid profiles as much as possible. Modern applications should strive to follow [rule 3 of 12 Factor app](https://12factor.net/config):

> The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables

With Spring Boot you would have environment variable `URL` environment variable and use it in Spring Boot as `${URL}`. Each environment would have this environment variable configured to correct value.